# Load Partial View Inside the Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, modal-dialog, adminlte

create partial view but it's not loaded inside the modal. I tried so many ways but still no luck to load partial view inside the modal. what I tried it is in down. I want to load another action method such as create method inside the modal window. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3he9CLXmASo
Above link is example i want to do like this.

This is my modal code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showGame").click(function() {
        var url = $("#gameModal").data("url");

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $("#gameContainer").html(data);

            $("#gameModal").modal("show");
        });
    });
});
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="gameModal" data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

This is my Partial view code

```
@model Mvc.Models.Company
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.URL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tstamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tstamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tstamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
<div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This is my Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Companies/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,Name,Address,PhoneNumber,URL,Email,Active,Tstamp,IsDeleted")] Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Companies.Add(company);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
   return View(company);
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any element named gameContainer. I think what you need is a <div id="gameContainer"></div> inside the <div class="modal-body"> or change the body div to <div id="gameContainer" class="model-body">. You may be getting the partial, but there doesn't seem to be any container that matches the place you are trying to store the result.

Comment: I change it like what you said but modal not opening

Comment: @Saman, You are trying to show the Create Company form into modal, am I right?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes.

Comment: See my answer! let me know if it works for you. also let me know if face any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write your modal related html code as follows:

```
// Button that will trigger the modal

 <button id="createCompanyButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Create Company</button>

// Your modal code

<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="createCompanyFormModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="createCompanyFormModalbody" class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#createCompanyButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $.ajax({
           url: '/Companies/Create',
           type: 'GET',
           success: function(data) {
                $('#createCompanyFormModalbody').html(data);
                $('#createCompanyFormModal').modal('show');
           },
           error: function() {
               alert("There is some problem in the service!")
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Now it should show the form into modal when click the `createCompanyButton` button.

Comment: I used your code. when I click the button it says "There is a problem in service"

Comment: @Saman Please check whether the `url` path is correct or not?

Comment: I need one favour from you. Can you help me

Comment: Sure! Wait. I shall knock you.

Comment: I need CRUD in modal. Can you help me

Comment: Can you send me a CRUD operation in Modal.

Comment: @Saman Follow this. This is my repository: it will help you. https://github.com/TanvirArjel/JQueryDataTableWithAspNetMVC . Don't forget to start it.

Comment: It's complicated for me. can you small example include CRUD inside modal window.

Comment: Can you help me to do this?

Comment: @Saman I am somewhat busy now! I shall knock you and try to help with remote access later of the day.